# strip character in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in Oracle where string starts with 011 and some of strings are perfect which I don't want to remove.
BY using this Oracle query I get this result

```
select termnum, substr(termnum,4) as New_TermNum from reject

   Termnum                New_Termnum
011390864324465           390864324465
011390465772400           390465772400
0117845300123             7845300123
6306900110                6900110
7893465126                3465126
```

I am looking to have New_Termnum column like this

```
   Termnum                New_Termnum
011390864324465           390864324465
011390465772400           390465772400
0117845300123             7845300123
6306900110                6306900110
7893465126                7893465126
```

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the `011` if and only if the string starts with `011`

```
select (case when substr(termnum,1,3) = '011'
             then substr(termnum,4)
             else termnum
         end) as newTermNum
  from reject
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `REGEXP_REPLACE` or `CASE` with `SUBSTR`:

```
SELECT termnum,
       REGEXP_REPLACE( termnum, '^011' ) AS new_termnum,
       CASE SUBSTR( termnum, 1, 3 )
            WHEN '011' THEN SUBSTR( termnum, 4 )
                       ELSE termnum
            END AS new_termnum2
FROM   reject;
```

**Output**:

```
TERMNUM         NEW_TERMNUM     NEW_TERMNUM2  
--------------- --------------- ---------------
011390864324465 390864324465    390864324465    
011390465772400 390465772400    390465772400    
0117845300123   7845300123      7845300123      
6306900110      6306900110      6306900110      
7893465126      7893465126      7893465126
```